# How can I open the .dmg install window on top of everything?

Tags: install, dmg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When opening a DMG file, how do I get it to open up in front of the windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/when-opening-a-dmg-file-how-do-i-get-it-to-open-up-in-front-of-the-windows)

Whenever I open up a .dmg file, it just gets opened, but it stays under everything that I've got open.
Right now I would have to launch Mission Control to see the opened .dmg window and then click on it, to become visible at the top.

How can I set it up to behave in a way, that when I open up a .dmg file, it gets displayed on top of everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a Finder (on Lion) issue and as such, there are no settings to tweak for your problem. 
A faster way to reach the mount window is to simply click the Finder icon in your Dock.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you wanna tell me the devs didn't think that a .dmg that i WANT to open , should be in the front for me to see after I click it ?? And rather have me going to some other place first, even if I clicked the icon so I can install it ??

Comment: Not really, I would consider it a Lion related bug. A dev overlook.

Comment: Ok. I hope I can find a fix for it.

Comment: This isn't a Lion bug, this issue was in Snow Leopard too.

Comment: Only in Lion for me.