# Disk image windows open beneath other windows

Tags: macos, mac, dmg

When I install software from a .dmg, the verification window pops up, which I suspect is normal. When it's done, though, the Finder window - you know, the "Drag to Applications to install" box - pops up **under everything else.** This is crazy-annoying.

After reading this other thread explaining how to craft a DMG with a script to surface the window, I now believe this is the normal behavior on Lion.

How might I "fix things" so I get a DMG to pop up without needing to [reprogram each one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/when-opening-a-dmg-file-how-do-i-get-it-to-open-up-in-front-of-the-windows)?

Comment: Same thing happens to me. This question also looks like a duplicate of: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/when-opening-a-dmg-file-how-do-i-get-it-to-open-up-in-front-of-the-windows

Comment: let's keep both questions. The other one is more about how can I roll my own DMG so that they don't follow the default behavior. This one can be for someone who figures out how to change the default behavior.

Comment: Sounds good to me, though I think it's true that this only seems to be an issue when opening DMGs around Google Chrome. Will test some more to make sure.

Comment: That's not "an installer," it's a disk image that has been mounted in Finder.

Comment: Really? With the often-customized graphics prompting the user to drag-and-drop to install? Looked like an installer to me.

Comment: Try to install something and then DON'T TOUCH YOUR COMPUTER DURING THE INSTALLATION. It maybe has something to do with what application has the focus. (Just a guess, and probably you did try already)

Comment: @11684, yeah, that was the first thing I tried. I'm an experienced linuxeur so I'm pretty sensitive to user-related focus problems.

Comment: @Kerin No, it isn't an installer, just a mounted image in a Finder window like fluffy noted. You can customize folder backgrounds with pictures, so many app DMGs use a picture to indicate that you should drag the .app bundle to Applications (and usually provide an alias to Applications for convenience).

Comment: I fail to see in what sense that isn't an installer, given that it behaves in all ways like one. It is a special mode of the Finder app invoked specifically to install an application, with installation-specific graphics and functionality. This discussion, while marginally enlightening, is irrelevant to the actual issue I asked about given that the behavior of the window (whatever its origin) is the actual, real matter at hand.

Comment: @Kerin Ever tried Apple-key (is that command?)+ tab when there is a log off or shut down dialog opened? You can try to focus Finder, but never the dialog is focused, except for when you click on. It might be such an unfocusable dialog.

Comment: Disk Images contain either a .app or a folder containing the .app. This app or folder is then dragged and dropped into /Applications. This is nothing more than copying the App. This is not "installing".

An Installer is a .pkg file typically built with PackageMaker (part of Xcode) and contains the files needed to run the App along with config files and extensions. These files are copied into place by Installer.app. Installer.app can also execute pre-install and post-install scripts.

Disk Image != Installer Package

Answer (score 1):

Digging around on Apple Discussions, I found [this hint](https://discussions.apple.com/message/8914665#8914665) for this problem:

In Terminal.app, execute (all on one line, no carriage return) 
(does not require sudo)

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister  -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

A successful run produces no output.

After doing that on my machine (OS X 10.8.2 12C60), the expected behavior for read-only `.dmg`'s momentarily occurs, i.e. when opening `.dmg`'s from Firefox or from the Downloads folder on the Dock, after accepting the license agreement (if one is present,) the Finder window for the `.dmg` pops to the foreground.

BUT, this desirable behavior only seems to last a matter of seconds before the old behavior (opening under other windows) recurs. Not sure what to make of it.  Probably some conflict going on within LaunchServices, either an Apple bug, or maybe interference from some other application.

In my case, I have a lot of third party file-system and UI tools such as PathFinder, DefaultFolderX, KeyboardMaestroX, etc, maybe one of these is to blame.